# Directory Structure within TreeView VB

Tags: asp.net, treeview

Started to look at the Treeview control.

Is there anyway to tie the Tree View control into a Directory structure on the Web Server using Visual basic?

I have a lot of legacy files, which are updated and added often. Obviously I could code the structure in XML but this would be laborious and hard to train out to the end user.

I guess it would be a dynamic creation of an XML file perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an elementary sample that I created awhile ago when learning to play with the TreeView. I have now converted the code to VB.NET using an [online converter](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/) for your benefit.

It recursively walks the directory tree starting from the root of the virtual directory and creates nodes for each sub-directory or file encountered. I think this is exactly what you needed.

For visual separation, I had used icons to differentiate files from folders (folder.gif and file.gif). You can remove that parameter if you want.

Complete ASPX follows (You can paste it into a new page and it should run):

---

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.IO" %>

<script runat="server">
  Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
      Dim rootDir As New DirectoryInfo(Server.MapPath("~/"))

      ' Enter the RecurseNodes function to recursively walk the directory tree. 
      Dim RootNode As TreeNode = RecurseNodes(rootDir)

      ' Add this Node hierarchy to the TreeNode control. 
      Treeview1.Nodes.Add(RootNode)
    End If
  End Sub

  Private Function RecurseNodes(ByVal thisDir As DirectoryInfo) As TreeNode
    Dim thisDirNode As New TreeNode(thisDir.Name, Nothing, "Images/folder.gif")

    ' Get all the subdirectories in this Directory. 
    Dim subDirs As DirectoryInfo() = thisDir.GetDirectories()
    For Each subDir As DirectoryInfo In subDirs
      thisDirNode.ChildNodes.Add(RecurseNodes(subDir))
    Next

    ' Now get the files in this Directory. 
    Dim files As FileInfo() = thisDir.GetFiles()
    For Each file As FileInfo In files
      Dim thisFileNode As New TreeNode(file.Name, Nothing, "Images/file.gif")
      thisDirNode.ChildNodes.Add(thisFileNode)
    Next

    Return thisDirNode
  End Function
</script>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <asp:treeview ID="Treeview1" runat="server"></asp:treeview>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

A custom sitemap provider is a good bet.

There is a good article on 4guys title "Examining ASP.NET 2.0's Site Navigation - Part 4 "